# Computing the unitary operator that diagonalizes a matrix

Tags: matrix

[image]

Hello. I am learning in Mathematica how to obtain the unitary operator that allows us to diagonalize the matrix M. Although with U^{-1}.M.U am able to obtain the answer: why doesn't the program deliver it diagonally? (I had to verify that such a matrix is diagonal)
Thank you.

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as copyable *Mathematica* code instead of just images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you. You may find [the meta Q&A, How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site,](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: @Michael From now on I will copy the code.

Comment: Note that `Eigensystem[]` on an exact matrix does not (usually) produce normalized eigenvectors. So you need to `Normalize[]` them, if you want to construct a unitary matrix from them.

Comment: Would that mean adding Normalize[v]?

Comment: To normalize each vector use `Map` (`/@`): `u = Transpose[Normalize /@ v]`. Or search for "normalize" in the documentation for `Eigensystem`; they show how to use it to diagonalize a matrix, more or less what you're doing here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> why doesn't the program deliver it diagonally?

Mathematica does not simplify automatically (for good reasons). So you just need to simplify the result. That is all.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
M = {{2, 3}, {3, 7}}
{lambda, v} = Eigensystem[M]
U = Transpose[v]
(Inverse[U] . M . U) // Simplify // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: You're right. By simplifying you could lose information. Thank you so much.

Comment: @eraldcoil if you are coming from system not symbolic (like Matlab) then `Simplify` will be new to you which is OK. in Matlab, since everything is numerical (vs. mix of numerical and Symbolics like in Mathematica), the concept of `Simplify` does not really apply as it is done automatically in Matlab and other systems like it (Fortran, etc..), since things are all numbers. But in CAS system `Simplify` becomes more important.  Be careful that `FullSimplify` if overdone can slow down things in long computation. But you can add `TimeConstrained` to avoid being stuck.